# How to create a component from a pre-existing one in Altium Summer 09?

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm using Altium summer 09, I need to use "D connector 15" , however, I need male and female connectors. I do not know which of them was made, male or female, in the footprint of the compenente "D connector 15" of the library "Miscellaneous Connectors Intlib" . So I figured I thought to copy the "D connector 15" that is available into the "Miscellaneous Connectors Intlib" library and create my own library to be able to modify it as I want. Does anyone know how to do this? I looked for some explanations on the internet, but it is not working. I did the following?

File »Open
 in the path C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Altium Designer Summer 09 \ Library
the file:  Miscellaneous Connectors

So, a window pop-up appeared and ask me to choose "Extract Sources" or "Install Library" I choose "Extract Sources".

Then, in projects, the extracted library appears.

[image]

However, I can not access the "D connector 15" component, nor the schematic nor the footprint. How then can I copy so I can generate another component from it?

[edited]

After to extract Micellaneous Connectors intlib, I openned the SchLib and PcbLib and, as I informed before, I couldn't find the component D connector 15, however, I did:

Tools -> Next Component

I kept doing this until the D connector 15 appeared. So, I could copy it and paste to my own library and modify it.

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166456/altium-09-copy-footprint-between-libraries

Comment: What happens when you try to open those libraries? Why don't you just make the connector from scratch?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  when I open Miscellaneous Connectors.SchLib appears a component, different of that I want to modify, but I don't know how to change to another.  When I open Miscellaneous Connectors.PcbLib nothing appears, only a gray screen. I am a beginner with Altium, and, for me, it is nothing intuitive, so, I thought if I start to generate a component from another, would be safer and faster.

Comment: I strongly suggest you work your way through some tutorials.

Comment: I would suggest not starting with the version of Altium you are using. If you want to learn and have paid for it then might as well learn the most recent version. Plus documentation is much greater for newer versions.